# Get all items with all properties using django multi-table inheritance and django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm using Django multi-table inheritance:

```py
class Parent():
   common_property = ...

class Child1(Parent):
   child1_specific_property = ...

class Child2(Parent):
   child2_specific_property = ...
```

And want to expose the list of **all** items on the same endpoint.

If I make a basic serializer and view for the `Parent` model, I would just get the common properties (the ones living on that model), but in this case I want to get all child-specific properties for every item. Ideally something like this:

```
items {
    type_1: {
      common_property
      child1_specific_property
    }
    type_2: {
      common_property
      child2_specific_property
    }
}
```

Am I missing any trivial way to do this?

Comment: There isn't a trivial way to do this. django-polymorphic is a package that automatically fetches the correct class of child model. And there are other packages that do similar things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up finding a *well* performing way to manually do this. A simpler option would be to use libraries like `django-polymorphic`, as @dirkgroten commented.

Models are defined using multi-table inheritance, as stated in my question:

```py
class Parent():
   common_property = ...

class Child1(Parent):
   child1_specific_property = ...

class Child2(Parent):
   child2_specific_property = ...
```

On the **serializer**, we overwrite the `to_representation` method in order to map every instance to the correct child serializer:

```py
from rest_framework import serializers


class Parent(serializers.BaseSerializer):

    def to_representation(self, instance):

        try:
            return Child_1_Serializer(instance=instance.child1).data
        except Child1.DoesNotExist:
            pass

        try:
            return Child_2_Serializer(instance=instance.child2).data
        except Child2.DoesNotExist:
            pass

        return super().to_representation(instance)
```

On the **view** we use `select_related` when defining the queryset, to avoid performing one query for every child when getting the list. More info about `select_related` can be found on the [Queryset API reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/).

```py
class ParentViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset = Parent.objects.all().select_related('child1').select_related('child2')
    serializer_class = ParentSerializer
```

Filter and other stuff can be added to the serializer as you would do with simple models.